# JSON serialization across managed packages

Tags: managed-package, json, serialization

We're having an ecosystem of managed packages where one is dependend on another and sometimes there is a need that one package (e.g. extension package) need to serialize some objects from another namespace (e.g. base package).

The most common struggle is error as follows:

> cannot serialize type from package **namespace**

Basically you can not call JSON.serialize on instance of a managed object outside of the managed pacakge (also package B can not serialize object from package A).

A specific problem that I have is that **BASE** package defines virtual class that is then extended by **EXTENSION** package. Objects that are instances of extension class will still contain some sub-properties that would be instances of subclasses from **BASE** namespace - and this result in failed attempt to JSON.serialize() such object.

So here is a structure that I'm working with:

**BASE Package** has some kind of virtual class - for example like this:

```
global virtual class CoreClass {

    global String name {get;set;}
    global InnerClassFromCore someProp {get;set;}

    global virtual void construct(String name, String subName, String subValue) {
        this.name = name;
        this.someProp = new InnerClassFromCore(subName, subValue);
    }

    global virtual class InnerClassFromCore {
        global String name {get;set;}
        global String value {get;set;}

        global InnerClassFromCore() {}     // dummy but required constructor

        global InnerClassFromCore(String name, String value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }    
}
```

**Extension Package** will have base package implementation:

```
global class CoreClassImpl extends masimtestcore.CoreClass {

    global String hereAreSomeExtensionProps {get;set;}
    ...

    global String serialize() {
        return JSON.serialize(this);
    }
}
```

In this case trying to execute following code:

```
CoreClassImpl cls = new CoreClassImpl(); 
cls.construct('name', 'subname', 'subvalue');
cls.serialize();
```

will result in:

> Line: 3, Column: 1 System.JSONException: Cannot serialize type from
>   package: masimtestcore.CoreClass.InnerClassFromCore

Question is how to overcome this?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge! I'm sure that this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Very nice. Please remember to come back tomorrow and accept your own answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Extension Package** should extend all sub-properties of a base class and before calling **JSON.serialize** we should convert instances of base subproperties into instances of extension sub-properties.

Example is presented in **serializeWithConversion** - this will be allowed replacement of pure JSON.serialize:

```
global class CoreClassImpl extends masimtestcore.CoreClass {

    global String someOtherProp {get;set;}

    global class InnerClassFromCoreImpl extends masimtestcore.CoreClass.InnerClassFromCore {
        global InnerClassFromCoreImpl(String name, String value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    global String serializeWithConversion() {
        masimtestcore.CoreClass.InnerClassFromCore toBeConverted = this.someProp;
        this.someProp = null;
        this.someProp = new InnerClassFromCoreImpl(toBeConverted.name, toBeConverted.value);
        return JSON.serialize(this);
    }
}
```

I hope this would save some time for the other people. We literally wasted gazillion of hours to understand how it works.